# How to create a common/parent ID to all the linked values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like below with all the links between multiple accounts.

```
Col1    Col2
----------
A   B
A   C
B   C
D   E
F   G
G   H
I   A
J   I
```

I would like to create common Id for all the links accounts. In the above example A,B,C,I,J are linked. So they should get same ID.

My end data should look something similar to below.

```
**ID    Parent_ID**
----------
A   1
B   1
C   1
D   2
E   2
F   3
G   3
H   3
I   1
J   1
```

Can anyone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have made your example so abstract it doesn't make much sense. Where do the numbers come from? You can greatly improve your question by following the advice here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ I suspect you will need a recursive cte to solve your issue but maybe we will more know once you provide more details.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Sean. Will start following that.

To answer your question,

Parent_Id is an incremental number that I need to create for the linked Names.

The input table shows you all the links.

Comment: But incremental from what? Why is A getting 1 and it doesn't increment again until D? I can help you here but you need to provide enough details so your question makes sense.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand your question. Sorry for the confusion.
As I said earlier,
record 1, A linked to B
record 2, A linked to C
record 3, B linked to C
record 7, I linked to A
record 8, J linked to I

so I consider A,B,C,I and J to be linked together, So I give them one common number.

Similarly 

record 4, D is linked to E and no other connections, So I give them the next parent id. 

record 5, F linked to G
record 6, G linked to H

F,G and H gets next parent id 

The output is basically assigning ID's like below.
A,B,C,I ,J  ----> 1
D,E     ----> 2
F,G, H      ----> 3

Comment: Typically in an adjacency list like this you have a way of determining the root elements. You have a root value and a parent value. Yours doesn't have that. Is ColA supposed to be the main row and ColB is the parent? The challenge is you don't have a main row for some of the other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is more elegant solution but I found this only (no `cursor`). `@tbl` is mutable so this variable is required.

```
declare @tbl table(id int identity(1,1), col1 char,col2 char)
insert @tbl values
('A',   'B'),
('A',   'C'),
('B',   'C'),
('D',   'E'),
('F',   'G'),
('G',   'H'),
('I',   'A'),
('J',   'I')

declare @c1 char, @c2 char, @par int=1, @rowcnt int,@id int, @tmpPar int
--target table
declare @groups table(col char,parent_id int)
--setup vars
select top 1 @c1=col1,@c2=col2, @id=id from @tbl order by id
--insert 2 rows into groups
insert @groups values(@c1,@par),(@c2,@par)
--remove processed row
delete @tbl where id=@id
set @rowcnt=@@ROWCOUNT

--do remaining in a cicle
while @rowcnt>0
begin
    select top 1 @c1=col1,@c2=col2, @id=id from @tbl order by id
    select @tmpPar=parent_id from @groups where col =@c1 or col= @c2
    --
    if @tmpPar is null
        select @tmpPar=@par+1,@par=@par+1--new group

    --add new rows
    insert @groups values(@c1,@tmpPar),(@c2,@tmpPar)
    delete @tbl where id=@id
    set @rowcnt=@@ROWCOUNT
    set @tmpPar=null --reset var
end

--final result
select distinct * from @groups
```